# MongoDB keeps generating a new id even after setting the id property when saving in the DB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In my application I generated ids using another database and I need to use this already created ids in mongo aswell. Setting the id before saving the object just returns an object with a generated id by mongo. Is there any configuration for the mongodb to not do this?

```
   SampleObject {
      private String id;
   }

   SampleObject sampleObject = new SampleObject();
   sampleObject.setId("f9de2416-1d10-11ec-a8b5-00ff37757c54");

   repository.save(sampleObject); // returns the object saved but with a different id (generated by mongo not what we set)
```

Comment: Isn't the `id` field in mongodb name as `_id`?

Comment: It is still mapped to the **id** field as according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you retry with the *Annotation of @Id*. Based on the document you need to annotate @Id to map to _id.

```
@Document
public class SampleObject {

  @Id
   private ObjectId id;

}
```

Comment: Done that and doesn't work.

Comment: The other thing to check is if @Id is imported from org.springframework.data.annotation.Id.

Comment: No, that won't do as well. I'm using that annotation.